# How to .log() an element that contains element that contains a text in Cypress

Tags: cypress

Basically I have 4 rows

**4 rows**
[image: Rows]

and I want to .log() only one of them which contains a label that has a text 'Car1.2'

**code**
[image: code]

**html**
[image: html]

**row code**
[image: row code]

Comment: Please add the code to your question and avoid adding screenshots. Also when you say you want to log the element, what do you want to log ?

Comment: I want to log '.row' with the label that has text 'Car1.2'

Comment: Where in the HTML is `.row`?

Comment: it is highlited on the html ss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this, if you want to just print the text `Car1.2`

```js
cy.contains('#label', 'Car1.2').then(($ele) => {
  cy.log($ele.text())
})
```

If you to print the whole row where `Car1.2` is printed, you first have to reach the parent element of the row and then using `within` scope the next commands within that specific row only and then print the row texts, something like this:

```js
cy.contains('#label', 'Car1.2')
  .parent()
  .parent()
  .parent()
  .parent()
  .within(() => {
    cy.get('#label').each(($ele) => {
      cy.log($ele.text())
    })
  })
```

To make sure all your commands automatically traverse shadow dom's, go to `cypress.json`(if cypress version < 10) or `cypress.config.js`(if cypress version >= 10) and write:

```js
includeShadowDom: true
```

Comment: I want to log the whole row, new image in the question

Answer (score 1):

There's another way to use `.contains()`, you can specify the `row` class as the first parameter and it will return the row having the label text "Carl1.2" somewhere inside it.

Combining two selectors used here `get('#chunker').find('.row')` allows you to do this

```js
cy.contains('#chunker .row', 'Carl1.2`)   // simple to obtain the row
  .then($row => {
    cy.log($row)
  })
```

Add `includeShadowDom:true` option to find the the label

```js
cy.contains('#chunker .row', 'Carl1.2`, {includeShadowDom:true})   
  .then($row => {
    cy.log($row)
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move to the parent row by specifying `.parents('.row')`

See [parents() command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/parents)

> Please note that .parents() travels multiple levels up the DOM tree as opposed to the .parent () command which travels a single level up the DOM tree.

Like this

```js
it('finds labels', {includeShadowDom:true}, () => {

  cy.contains('#chunker #label', 'Car1.2')
    .parents('.row')
    .then($row => {
      cy.log($row.text())
    })
})
```